# Is there a list of events for when Heroku runs scripts?

Tags: heroku

I find the documentation at - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#scripts - is poor.  It doesn't list all of the different events which can be hooked into to run scripts.  I want to run a script for when the app is first created and another with each release.  The first is objective is already achieved with a script with runs on the "postdeploy" event.  I can't see anything though to help with the second.  If using a procfile I know I just specify the "release" process type but I'm trying to do this with an app.json file so I believe the procfile is not relevant.

Does anybody know how I can do what I want?  Even better the whereabouts of this explained on Heroku.

At the moment I have this for my app.json -

```
{
    "name": "accounts",
    "success_url": "/users/signup",
    "addons": [
        {
            "plan": "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
        }
    ],
    "env": {
        "NEW_USERS_ARE_SUPERUSERS": "0"
    },
    "formation": {
        "web": {
            "quantity": 1,
            "size": "free",
            "command": "gunicorn proj.wsgi"
        }
    },
    "buildpacks": [
        {
            "url": "heroku/python"
        }
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "postdeploy": "psql -c \"create extension pg_trgm\" $DATABASE_URL && ./bin/setup.sh"
    }
}
```

Can I just add a "release" key to the "scripts" dictionary?  I saw somewhere somebody had "heroky-postbuild" but that didn't seem to work when I tried it.